# group by two columns in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to group by two columns? So the cross product is drawn
by `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth()`?

As example:

```
frame <- data.frame(
 series <- rep(c('a', 'b'), 6), 
 sample <- rep(c('glass','water', 'metal'), 4), 
 data <- c(1:12))

ggplot(frame, aes()) # ...
```

Such that the points `6` and `12` share a group, but not with `3`.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Taking the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598953/geom-line-connects-points-mapped-to-different-groups), using `interaction` to combine two columns into a new factor:

```
# Data frame with two continuous variables and two factors 
set.seed(0)
x <- rep(1:10, 4)
y <- c(rep(1:10, 2)+rnorm(20)/5, rep(6:15, 2) + rnorm(20)/5)
treatment <- gl(2, 20, 40, labels=letters[1:2])
replicate <- gl(2, 10, 40)
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, treatment=treatment, replicate=replicate)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape = replicate,
  group=interaction(treatment, replicate))) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot example]

Answer (score 65):

for example:

```
 qplot(round, price, data=firm, group=id, color=id, geom='line') +  
      geom_smooth(aes(group=interaction(size, type)))
```

Answer (score 39):

Why not just `paste` those two columns together and use *that* variable as groups?

```
frame$grp <- paste(frame[,1],frame[,2])
```

A somewhat more formal way to do this would be to use the function `interaction`.

Comment: I think you shouldn't modify your `data.frame` for the purpose of a plot. The `plot` should plot your df and not the opposite.

Comment: I agree, Blue Magister's answer is better.

Comment: @clemlaflemme I think BlueMagister's answer is fine, although I think the distinction in this case is quite minor. But the general position that one should not modify your data frame for a plot is a curious one given your choice to use **ggplot2**, the entire design of which is premised on explicitly structuring your data to work with ggplot's semantics.

Comment: A disadvantage of `paste` is that when input is a factor, it discards the levels, where `interaction` preserves the order of the original factors.  This means that the groups are more naturally ordered with `interaction` approach.

Comment: A disadvantage of `interaction` is that it can drop `NA`'s. Consider the example: `paste(c("a","b", NA, NA), c(1,2,1,2))` which results in four different grouping variables: `"a 1"  "b 2"  "NA 1" "NA 2"`, while `interaction(c("a","b", NA, NA), c(1,2,1,2))` generates only three grouping variables.

Comment: you can use `paste` within the `aes(group = paste(treatment, replicate))` and never modify `d`