# Dodge by another group with ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line over a bunch of points by certain groups. For example, I have:

```
x = rep(c('fruit', 'vegetable'), 15)
z = c(rep(c(rep('fresh', 2), rep('ripe', 2), rep('rotten', 2)), 5)
s = c(rep('pick1', 6), rep('pick2', 6), rep('pick3', 6), rep('pick4', 6), rep('pick5', 6))

y = runif(30, min=11, max=15)
low = rep(c(0, 1), 15)
y[low == 1] = y[low == 1] - 10
y[low == 0] = y[low == 0] - 5

groceries_df = data.frame(type=x, value=y, age=z, species=s)
```

where type is either "fruit" or "vegetable", age is either "fresh", "ripe", or "rotten", and species is a unique list of different picks from a store, so there are 2*3 = 6 values for each species. I am grouping these values on a discrete x-axis defined by their age, and they are grouped by their type (and thus dodged by their type).

```
dodge = position_dodge(width=0.9)
p = ggplot(groceries_df, aes(factor(age), value, color=factor(type), shape=factor(type))) +
           geom_jitter(position=dodge) +
           geom_line(data=groceries_df[groceries_df$type == 'fruit',],     aes(group=factor(species)), position=dodge) +
           geom_line(data=groceries_df[groceries_df$type == 'vegetable',], aes(group=factor(species)), position=dodge)
```

This code produces a plot extremely close to what I want, but I noticed that geom_line dodges by species, not by type. It seems as though I just need to redirect the dodge, even though I need the actual lines to be grouped by species (so I can see the transition of one species' value from one type to the next at all ages). Is there any way to redirect dodge?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible sample ?

Comment: I added a numerical example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to add new column to your existing data frame which will contain combination of `type` and `species` columns (those two columns are actually needed to group points for lines) (Idea taken from this @joran [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968976/group-by-two-columns-in-ggplot2)).

```
groceries_df$comb<-paste(groceries_df$type,groceries_df$species)
```

Then just use this new column as `group=`. This way you also need less comandlines.

```
ggplot(groceries_df,aes(age,value,color=type,shape=type,group=comb))+
  geom_jitter(position=dodge)+geom_line(position=dodge)
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close, but what if I want to also include a boxplot of the data at each type for each age (geom_boxplot(aes(color=factor(regions)), outlier.color=NA, outlier.shape=NA, position=dodge))? The boxes are clumped together in the wrong locations due to the pasting (this misplacing of the points also occurs if I try to draw the mean of the points using errorbar).

Comment: Alright, I have solved this issue by using interaction:

geom_boxplot(gorceries_original, aes(color=factor(type), group=interaction(age, type)), outlier.color=NA, outlier.shape=NA, position=dodge)

However, as with the errorbar-mean, the jitter points appear on the wrong side. Is there a reason for this occurrence?

Comment: I have also solved this new issue by flipping the levels of the column, so this issue is completely resolved.

Comment: @user1104160 would be awesome if you had posted your answer