# `geom_line()` connects points mapped to different groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to `group` my data based on the interaction of two variables, but only map an aesthetic to one of those variables. (The other variable represents replicates which should, in theory, be equivalent to each other). I can find inelegant ways to do this, but it seems like there ought to be more elegant way to do it.

For example

```
# Data frame with two continuous variables and two factors 
set.seed(0)
x <- rep(1:10, 4)
y <- c(rep(1:10, 2)+rnorm(20)/5, rep(6:15, 2) + rnorm(20)/5)
treatment <- gl(2, 20, 40, labels=letters[1:2])
replicate <- gl(2, 10, 40)
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, treatment=treatment, replicate=replicate)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, shape=replicate)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

This almost gets it right, except that I don't want to represent the points with different shapes. It seems like `group=interaction(treatment, replicate)` would help (e.g based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968976/group-by-two-columns-in-ggplot2), but `geom_line()` still connects points in different groups:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, group=interaction("treatment", "replicate"))) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

I can solve the problem by manually creating an interaction column and `group`ing by that:

```
d$interact <- interaction(d$replicate, d$treatment)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, group=interact)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

but it seems like there ought to be a more `ggplot2`-native way of getting `geom_line` to only connect points from the same group.

Comment: Why you put `interaction("treat", "replicate")` in second example not the actual names of columns? For me `group=interaction(treatment, replicate)` gives expected result

Comment: possible duplicate of [group by two columns in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968976/group-by-two-columns-in-ggplot2)

Comment: The difference is that in the cited question (which I meant to link originally, now have edited to add the link) the answer _does_ use quotes - but it also uses `qplot`. I guess `qplot` needs the variables in quotes, whereas `ggplot` takes them directly.

Comment: That linked answer appears to be incorrect. `qplot(x,y, d, colour=treatment, group=interaction("treatment", "replicate"), geom = "line")` does not work. I will make the necessary edits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code works if you do the following. I think you had a problem because `aes` treated `"treat"` and `"replicate"` as vectors, so it was equivalent to `group = 1`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=treatment, group=interaction(treatment, replicate))) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```