# How to connect all points on a y-axis to x-axis points of same group ggplot through a line graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm new to R and been playing around with some ggplot logic for a friend. Where I'm trying to connect all points on a Y-axis to the points on the x-axis that belong to the same group. But my Y-axis points are also being connected which I don't want

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x= Letter_coding, y= Lectin_C, group=Island, 
color = Island)) +
geom_line()+
geom_point()
```

Something like this.

[image]

[image: But I’m trying to achieve this]

**Edit 1:**

Sample data:

```
Organism            Letter_coding   Island          Lectin_C    
Coral (Pocillopora)     A           FlintMos3_2     77.42858683 
Coral (Pocillopora)     A           FlintMos3_2     206.5272288 
C-A (Red Algae)         B           FlintMos3_2     201.8928979 
Coral (Porites)         C           FlintMos3_5     100.0270507 
Coral (Porites)         C           FlintMos3_5     116.1427727 
C-A (Red Algae)         D           FlintMos3_5     113.2093909 
Coral (Porites)         E           FlintMos5_2     148.1921679 
C-C                     F           FlintMos5_2     140.8645009 
Coral (Porites)         E           FlintMos5_2     120.3082097 
Coral (Porites)         G           MaldInv         259.2967552 
Coral (Porites)         G           MaldInv         238.4524644 
C-A (CCA)               H           MaldInv         58.82896626 
Coral (Porites)         C           StarTent        137.056068  
Coral (Porites)         C           StarTent        107.1444611 
C-A (Red Algae)         D           StarTent        120.4673744 
Coral (Porites)         G           VostMos_2       162.9043976 
Coral (Porites)         G           VostMos_2       202.3885923 
C-A (CCA)               H           VostMos_2       144.3439106
Coral (Porites)         I           VostMos_4       309.4388754 
Coral (Porites)         I           VostMos_4       276.9731826 
C-C                     J           VostMos_4       170.3126185
Coral (Montipora)       I           VostMos_4       181.4586178 
Coral (Montipora)       I           VostMos_4       158.7184731
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Please supply sample data.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @r2evans Updated the question with sample data

Comment: That sample data is a good start, but three rows does not (1) demonstrate sufficient variability, nor does it (2) match your sample plots. Additionally, it's hard to "consume", since I cannot easily just highlight, copy, and paste into an R buffer. Please use something like `dput(head(x,n=10))` (assuming 10 rows provides sufficient variability).

Comment: @r2evans Updated with real data. Hope this is helpful

Comment: I am struggling to see the difference between the charts, except that the red line appears obscured in the second one.

Comment: @neilfws The major difference is when you look at the lines between the points A and B I’m basically trying to achieve where point on A is connected to the point on B. But the points on the Y-axis of A shouldnt be linked to each other.

Comment: *"The major difference is when you look at the lines between the points A and B I’m basically trying to achieve where point on A is connected to the point on B."* I have no idea what you're saying; I agree with @neilfws, the only difference between the plots is a thinner red line connecting both `A` points. Is that what you want to do? Make the lines thinner?

Comment: Two things: your suggested grouping (textual) does not agree with your shown lines (graphic). The two points are identical in all columns except `$Lectin_C`; if that is the point, then there are other rows that should also not have connecting lines (e.g., 4,5; 10,11; 13,14; ...). You need to clarify your logic and your intended output, since what you've offered so far is inconsistent. Second: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968976/group-by-two-columns-in-ggplot2

Comment: I have updated the question with all relevant details thats the real data being used to generate the graph. I have updated the second picture with the a rough sketch of the goal.

Comment: @r2evans will look at the link to see if that is helpful

Comment: I think your logic is that you want no line to go vertically; they should always change from group (letter) to group before coming back. Unfortunately, there is nothing in your data to suggest that this is even relevant, nor any sustainable robust logic to ensure it always happens the way you want. A tangential question that might be relevant: Why is going from A to B and back to A meaningful, and how is it supported by the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to group data by island and then connect the Coral organisms to the C_ organisms by lines.  You can do this in a straightforward way by using several functions from tidyverse as shown below.

```
#
# Load tidyverse which includes the ggplot2, dplyr, and stringr packages  
#
   library(tidyverse)
#
#  Data should be in island_data
#  Separate Coral and C_ organisms
#
   coral <- island_data %>% filter(str_detect(Organism, "Coral"))
   C_dash <- island_data %>% filter(str_detect(Organism, "C-"))
#
#   Make data for line segment ends by joining coral and C_ data
#
   plt_data <- left_join(coral, C_dash, by = "Island", suffix = c("","_C") ) 
   sp <-  plt_data %>% ggplot(aes( color = Island)) +  
          geom_segment(aes( x= Letter_coding, y = Lectin_C, xend = Letter_coding_C, yend = Lectin_C_C), size=1.1) +
           geom_point(aes(x= Letter_coding, y=Lectin_C), size = 4) +
           geom_point(aes(x = Letter_coding_C, y = Lectin_C_C), size = 4)

   plot(sp)
```

This gives the plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will state at the outset that this answer is not a direct answer to your question. I think you need to address two issues.

First: what is the rationale for connecting the points using lines? Generally, we do this when there is change over time. That is not apparent in your data.

Second: what is it about the data that you want to convey in the chart? I see a dependent variable, `Lectin_C`, and two categories: `Island` and `Organism`. The letter coding I do not fully understand. So what's interesting? Is it `Lectin_C` content by island, or by organism, or perhaps by both?

If I were plotting this data, I'd plot the values as jittered points, colour by one of island or organism and split the data into groups (facets) by organism or island. As an example, if we are primarily interested in `Lectin_C` by `Organism`:

```
library(tidyverse)
coral_data %>% 
ggplot(aes(Letter_coding, Lectin_C)) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color = Island)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Organism) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or conversely, if we want to look at `Lectin_C` by Island:

[image]