# R Highcharter hcaes- Area chart staking by only 1 factor... with 2 grouping factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, aes, interaction

I am trying to achieve something like what is reported in this post ([group by two columns in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968976/group-by-two-columns-in-ggplot2)), but with an additional feature.

I am currently creating my highchart grouping by 2 factors: this solution is working just fine.

What I would like to achieve is: I would like to stack the area chart by only 1 of the 2 factors, and use the other one to have 2 overlapping "stacked" area charts

Do you have any clue how to make it?

Best,
Lorenzo

Comment: Hi, are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xv4g2cma/ 2 stacked series and one separate non-stacked?

Comment: Hi @raf18seb, thanks for your help: something kinda like what you have shown! "series1" and "series2" of your chart are perfect. Instead of "series 3", I would need something like series1&2 (let's call'em "series3" and "series4", so two stacked area charts) which overlaps "series1&2". So, as if series1&2 have their independent y axis, and series3&4 have their own y axis. Hope I explained myself a bit more clear :)

Comment: Am I getting closer? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/43ncukmw/ ---   after you approve the JavaScript version, I will help you rewrite it to R

Comment: @raf18seb yes! Exactly like that!

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I am adding the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you approved that you are trying to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/43ncukmw/

Here you have the R code of this chart:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = 'normal')) %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(min = 0, max = 20),
    list(min = 0, max = 16, opposite = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), type = 'area') %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), type = 'area') %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3), type = 'column', yAxis = 1) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3), type = 'column', yAxis = 1)
```